# Запрос в базу через php, слетает кодировка

Tags: php, sql, кодировка

Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `realname` = '$customer' LIMIT 1
```

У меня в базе русские имена.

Если я через форму пытаюсь вписать ник и попытаться вывести - у меня слетает кодировка.

```
// Через форму вписываю параметр realname
$customer = $_POST['customer'];// приходит "ааы"
```

Но в таком случае, запрос выдаст 0 результатов...

А если  я напрямую в файле напишу переменную, с значением: "ааы", и подставлю в запрос - результат будет.

Но вот какой прикол случается:

```
$customer = $_POST['customer'];// приходит "ааы"
$file_customer = 'ааы';
```

Если вывести переменную созданую напрямую в файле, выведет:

```
Р°Р°С‹ // и если этот результат подставить в sql запрос - выведет результат.
```

Файл в кодировке utf8.
База , и таблица в кодировке utf8.
При открытии соединения ставлю

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

В чем может быть беда?...

Answer (score 3):

На каждой странице я прописываю

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Ну а когда подключаюсь к БД. в конфиге прописываю вот так

```html
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Answer (score 2):

Дабы не мучаться, напишите в файле .htaccess (если файла нет, создайте)
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Ответ таков, что из формы приходили данные в кодировке cp1251...

```
$customer = iconv("cp1251", "utf-8", $customer);
```